# Select distinct random images in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, random, distinct-values

I have an issue about Kotlin code, I have a task where I have to generate images randomly from an array, but the thing is that they have to be distinct from each other. There are four images views and after clicking on them, one of those Views has to change its source randomly. I have wrote this code, but the images are not distinct

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    private val images = arrayOf(
        R.mipmap.fruit,
        R.mipmap.banana,
        R.mipmap.watermelon,
        R.mipmap.apricot,
        R.mipmap.cherry,
        R.mipmap.strawberry,
        R.mipmap.melon,
        R.mipmap.kiwi
    )
    private lateinit var imageViews:Array<ImageView>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        init()

    }

    private fun init() {

        imageViews = arrayOf(imageView_1, imageView_2, imageView_3, imageView_4)
        imageView_1.setOnClickListener(this)
        imageView_2.setOnClickListener(this)
        imageView_3.setOnClickListener(this)
        imageView_4.setOnClickListener(this)
    }


    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        randomImageView().setImageResource(randomImage())
    }

    private fun randomImage() = images[(images.indices).random()]
    private fun randomImageView() = imageViews[(imageViews.indices).random()]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make `imageViews` a map that also tracks what images are set on the views. Then you can choose your random images from a reduced set by removing in-use images from the selection pool.

```
private val imageViews = MutableMap<ImageView, Int?>()

// in init ...
imageViews.putAll(listOf(imageView_1, imageView_2, imageView_3, imageView_4).map { it to null })

// ...

override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    val view = randomImageView()
    val image = randomImage()
    view.setImageResource(image)
    imageViews[view] = image
}

fun randomImage() = (images - imageViews.values).random()
```

Comment: And how will the function randomImageView() look like in this case?

Comment: `private fun randomImageView() = imageViews.keys.random()`

Comment: Oh, and `images` should be a List rather than an Array to make the minus operator available.